# How can I get the URL of a view within a view?

Tags: django

In a Django template, I can get the URL of a view via

```
{% url my_view arg1 %}
```

How can I do that same thing in a view such as

```
def my_view(request):
  view_url = some_how_get_view_url('name_of_my_view')
  return HttpResponse('<a href="' + view_url + '"> Hello world.</a>')
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You're looking for the `django.core.urlresolvers.reverse` function.

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/http/urls/#reverse-resolution-of-urls

It's exactly what the `{% url %}` tag does behind the scenes.

```
url = reverse('my_view', args=['arg1'])
```